Critique a key expansion scheme based on primes
The idea is to take to random 0/1 strings of co-prime length and XOR them periodically, e.g.
A = 101 (length 3) and B = 10011 (length 5)
101101101101101   A x 5
100111001110011   B x 3
---------------   XOR
001010110011110   aperiodic(?) sequence of length 5*3 = 15

You could use this to encode a secret text of length 3x5=15 after transmitting 3+5 bits of secret key. This becomes more interesting when using partial keys of large prime length (order of magnitude of RSA cypher); you transmit A+B bits, but get a much longer expanded key. Each sub-sequence of the expanded key is used exactly once, and since sequence lengths of A and B are co-prime, the resulting sequence should be a) aperiodic and b) apparently completely random. This would grant a similar strength as RSA, being based on factorization. Also, the whole key sequence or even its total length will likely never be exposed to an attacker, since there's arbitrarily much expanded key to go around.
Now, of course this can't be perfectly safe, but where's the exploitable weakness?

Why is there a one-time-pad tag here?

This is quite vulnerable if an attacker can find/guess some bits of the key sequence.  For example, if the attacker knows (or guesses) that the plaintext is ASCII text encoded in bytes, that then reveals every 8th bit of the key stream.  If the attacker also knows (or can guess) the two primes, and that 1/8 of the bits gives them at least p+q bits of the key stream, they can then directly solve for the two original strings.

And, the primes are easy to guess (there aren't that many possibilities, and the correct guess is easy to verify in the ASCII text encoded example)
